# How to call enum method basis on what type it is passed?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

I have below Enum as shown below from which I need to call its appropriate method basis on what type of event it is.

```
public enum EventType {

  EventA {
    // cannot call this method
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> execute(String eventMapHolder) {
      final Map<String, String> holder = parseStringToMap(eventMapHolder);
      if (holder.isEmpty() || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(holder.get("m_itemId"))) {
        return ImmutableMap.of();
      }
      String itemId = holder.get("m_itemId");
      Map<String, String> clientInfoHolder = getClientInfo(itemId);
      holder.putAll(clientInfoHolder);
      return ImmutableMap.<String, Map<String, String>>builder().put(EventA.name(), holder)
          .build();
    }
  },
  EventB {
    // cannot call this method
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> execute(String eventMapHolder) {
      final Map<String, String> holder = parseStringToMap(eventMapHolder);
      if (holder.isEmpty() || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(holder.get("m_itemId"))) {
        return ImmutableMap.of();
      }
      return ImmutableMap.<String, Map<String, String>>builder().put(EventB.name(), holder)
          .build();
    }
  };

  public Map<String, String> parseStringToMap(String eventMapHolder) {
    // parse eventMapHolder String to Map
  }

  public Map<String, String> getClientInfo(final String clientId) {
    Map<String, String> clientInfoMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    // code to populate this map
    return clientInfoMap;
  }

  public Map<String, String> getDeviceInfo(final String itemId) {
    Map<String, String> deviceInfoMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    // code to populate this map
    return deviceInfoMap;
  }
}
```

**Question:**

For example: If I get `"EventA"`, then I want to call it's `execute` method. Similarly if I get `"EventB"` then I want to call it's `execute` method and so on. Right now it is not working because of obvious reason as it is not able to find `execute` method in the same enum.

```
String eventType = String.valueOf(payload.get("eventType"));
String eventMapHolder = String.valueOf(payload.get("eventMapHolder"));
// this below line gives compilation error as it is not able to find execute method.
Map<String, Map<String, String>> processedMap = EventType.valueOf(eventType).execute(eventMapHolder);
```

I need to perform certain actions depending on what types of events is passed.

- If `"EventA"` is passed, then first I am converting `eventMapHolder` string into Map (let's call this holder) and then I extract `itemId` from that holder map and then I pass `itemId` to `getClientInfo` method which in turn returns a Map (let's call this clientInfoHolder). And then I put everything from `clientInfoHolder` map into `holder` map and then finally return another Map based on `holder` along with its key.
- If `"EventB"` is passed, then first I am converting `eventMapHolder` string into Map (let's call this holder) and then I make a new immutable map basis on `holder` map along with its key and return that map.

In general I will have more event types in the same enum class and mostly they will do same operation as EventA and EventB.

What is the right and oop way to make this work? How can I call method of that particular enum type?

If there is any other better way or any other design pattern to do this then I am open for suggestions as welll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define abstract methods on an `enum`, so long as you override that method in each enumerated instance. Here's a simple example:

```
public enum EnumWithMethod {

  VALUE_A {
    @Override
    public String enumMethod(String s) {
      return s + "-A";
    }
  },
  VALUE_B{
    @Override
    public String enumMethod(String s) {
      return s + "-B";
    }
  };

  public abstract String enumMethod(String s);

}
```

Thus, given an arbitrary Enum instance, you can call the `enumMethod`:

```
EnumWithMethod e = EnumWithMethod.VALUE_A;
String str = e.enumMethod("asdf"); //asdf-A
```

For your example, this is as simple as adding

```
public abstract Map<String, Map<String, String>> execute(String eventMapHolder);
```

To your `EventType` enum.

Comment: Understood now.. Thanks for the help. Do you think this is the right pattern for this kind of problem using enum here and writing bunch of code in the same enum class? In general I will have around 15 EventTypes in that enum so my class will be very big. Do you see any other pattern that can do the same thing and may be well suited for this kind of problem?

Comment: The biggest upside to this approach is that it forces you to implement the method in every instance. The main alternative is one massive `switch` block, either here or in a helper utility class, but I get nervous when I see those because it's very easy (especially as the project grows) to forget to update it when you add a new enum value. If you're only doing the one method, I think this is fine. If you start to implement a ton of them, maybe pull those methods out to different classes?